# How to import modules from stack's extra-deps?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell stack project, and I'm trying to import the module `Cardano.CLI.Run` exposed by `cardano-cli`.

`cardano-cli` is a folder within the repository `cardano-node`:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node

So, I have added the following to my stack.yaml file (extra-deps):

```
# cardano-node, version 1.35.2
- git: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node.git
  commit: 7612a245a6e2c51d0f1c3e0d65d7fe9363850043
  subdirs:
    - cardano-cli
    - cardano-node
```

However, when I try to build the project, I get an error:

```
% stack build          
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 9.0, and using 9.2.3, this may fail
Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 3.4, but version 3.6.3.0 was found, this may fail
summon-api-server> build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library for summon-api-server-0.1.0.0..
Building library for summon-api-server-0.1.0.0..
[2 of 2] Compiling Lib

/Users/xyz/dr/xsf/my-project/src/Lib.hs:23:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Cardano.CLI.Run’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
23 | import Cardano.CLI.Run (runClientCommand)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What else do I gotta do?

Comment: add it to the `build-depends` section of the `.cabal` file.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem, when I add it, `stack build` removes it though.

Comment: Ok, I've added the deps to `package.yaml` file, and it does get added to the .cabal file. However, I now get a different error message:

`Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for cardano-cli-1.35.2:
    base-4.16.2.0 from stack configuration does not match ==4.14.*  (latest matching version is 4.14.3.0)
    canonical-json needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version is 0.6.0.0)

   ...
needed due to summon-api-server-0.1.0.0 -> cardano-cli-1.35.2`

Comment: It looks like `cardano-cli` may not be well-prepared to be used by downstream packages. The `base` constraint indicates that `cardano-cli` expects to be built with GHC 8.10, as opposed to GHC 9.2, which you're currently using. (https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/libraries/version-history is a good reference on the boot library versions.) Regarding the other dependency issues, you can probably resolve these by adding more `extra-deps`.

Comment: Cardano is built against `ghc-8.10.7`. I'd recommend to use `cabal` instead of `stack` for the cardano ecosystem.

Comment: @Ismor, thanks I've started using cabal directly, and it's now upto the point where it starts compiling and doesn't complain about dependencies anymore. However, I'm facing some compilation issues that I gotta get through.

Comment: Thanks all, I made changes to my project and this is the resulting repo: https://github.com/omefire/api-server

However:
- My goal is to import cabal-cli and cabal-node (https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node) as dependencies
- I want to use the module Cardano.CLI.Run (renderClientCommandError, runClientCommand)
- However, after creating a cabal.project file in my repo above, and adding dependencies to it, I keep getting an error when I do cabal v2-build
- Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I get this error message when I try to builld with `cabal build`:

--src/Cardano/Crypto/Hashing.hs:122:15: error:
    --    • Could not deduce (B.Buildable b0)
    --        arising from a use of ‘toAesonError’
    --      from the context: HashAlgorithm algo
    --        bound by the instance declaration
    --        at src/Cardano/Crypto/Hashing.hs:121:10-61
    --      The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    --      These potential instances exist:
    --        instance B.Buildable Void -- Defined in ‘Formatting.Buildable’
...

Comment: --        instance B.Buildable IntPtr -- Defined in ‘Formatting.Buildable’
--        instance B.Buildable WordPtr -- Defined in ‘Formatting.Buildable’
    --        ...plus 25 others
    --        ...plus 19 instances involving out-of-scope types
    --        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    --    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘toAesonError’
    --      In the first argument of ‘(<=<)’, namely
    --        ‘toAesonError . readEither’
    --      In the expression: toAesonError . readEither <=< parseJSON

Comment: I don't understand how anyone has been able to do this before,